# SQL INNER JOIN not joining correctly?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly new to SQL and PHP in general. I'm making a small searchbar for my website (a school project), and I have three tables that has been set in relation with a fourth. I used following SQL code (only looking at the first table I want to join):

```
SELECT  `band`.`bands`, `diskografi`.`FKband` 
FROM `band` 
INNER JOIN `diskografi` 
ON `band`.`id` = `diskografi`.`FKband`
```

Which gives my this table:

http://puu.sh/7VnOJ.png

It looks to me like it's not joining correctly, but I'm figuring it might be me not understanding SQL.
Right now I can only search through my band table (can be seen below).

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM band WHERE bands LIKE '%$searchq%'")
```

I want to be able to search through this table, and still get the band name.

Comment: Try removing the `diskografi` from the `SELECT` clause. Use only the field names.

Comment: what do you mean by "band.bands seem to overwrite diskografi.id"? That does not make much sense to me. Why don't you show your tables, the contents and the expected output? That might be easier to fix :)

Comment: Sounds like you have duplicate bands in you `band` table?

Comment: You don't select `diskografi.id` in the query, so how can you tell it overwrites it?

Comment: When you use inner join you treat the joined tables like you would the table it was joined to. You don't need to select the other table.

Comment: @iamsleepy Just me not understanding how it works. I deleted the `diskografi`.`FKband` and it seems to be in order.

Do you know how I need to write this into my PHP script, in order to be able to search for the bands?

Comment: You want to search in which field ? You want to use `LIKE` or `WHERE` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing a join, you can leave the joined table from the `FROM` clause. Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM band
                     INNER JOIN diskografi ON band.id = diskografi.FKband
                     WHERE bands
                     LIKE '%$searchq%'");
```

I hope this is for testing purpose only. Because using `mysql_query` is not safe and has been deprecated. You are better off using `PDO` or `mysqli` with prepared statments.

Comment: It worked, thank you.
It's only for testing, so security is none of my concerns.